# how can i break a String into characters in MIPS assembly,byte by byte.Basicly i want to take a user inputed array and print its letters one by one

Tags: string, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

```
.data
str10:   .asciiz "Give me a string:\n "

.align 2
B: .Space 100
.align 2
C: .Space 100

.text

main:

add $10,$0,$0


StringChanger:
addi $12,$0,100 
addi $11,$0,0       #j
addi $13,$0,0       #i
la $a0,str10
li $v0,4
syscall
li $v0,8
la $a0,C
li $a1,100      #arrays length
syscall

la $t0,1($a0)
lb $t1,($t0)
move $v0,$t1
li $v0,4
syscall
```

Comment: `lb` or `lbu` sign- or zero-extends a byte from memory into a register, and you're already using that.  Do that in a loop with an increment to the address.  Your code is an unreadable mess because you didn't use code formatting, but I don't see any branch instructions.  Obviously you need to loop.

Comment: yeah sry about the code format ,the thing is that for some reason it prints the whole string not just the 1st character.So i want it to work for 1 first then i will add the loop

Comment: v0=4 / syscall is print-string.  v0=11 / syscall is print character.  Read the manual: http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html

Comment: thanks for your time but it just prints ''D'' every time

Comment: The syscall takes its arg in `$a0`, so you need to `lbu $a0, C($t0)` or something.